# What does the bold sentence mean in the following excerpt?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, phrases, semantics

> In pennsylvania, a celebrity cardiologist who rages against the inflated price of crudités faces a tattooed lieutenant governor with heart trouble. In Georgia, the choice is between a pastor on one side and a former star of “Celebrity Apprentice” and “Celebrity Cook-Off” on the other. In November the results of these contests, and a few others like them, will determine control of the us Senate for the next two years. On this hinges the ability of the White House to staff its administration, to confirm judicial nominations and to pursue legislation.
>
> Because so much is riding on this election, The Economist has built a statistical model to try to predict what will happen. Our past forecasts—of France’s presidential elections in 2017 and 2022, America’s midterms of 2018 and its presidential election of 2020—all favoured the eventual victor months in advance. **Of course, a probabilistic forecast that correctly puts a 70% chance on something happening will look wrong 30% of the time.**

What does the bold sentence mean, and how could you paraphrase it?

Comment: Are you asking what 'probabilistic' means, or is there something else you don't understand?

Comment: The word probablilistic is not needed to understand the sentence, and the rest of the sentence is in very simple English, so I imagine that you are unclear about probability. If you toss a coin, the probability of it landing heads is 50% and tails 50%. Imagine a weighted coin, where the probabiliity was 70% heads and 30% tails: you would be inclined to call heads every time, but 30% of the time you would be wrong. If you only did it once, and the coin landed tails, the probability (forecast) would look (seem) wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It means that people mistake probability for promise, and that they judge the forecaster to be wrong when the less probable outcome happens.

The writer claims that if the weather network says there's a 70% chance of rain, and it doesn't rain, a person might say "The forecast was wrong!" But the forecast wasn't wrong -- it just looked wrong, I guess because people implicitly believe that the more probable event will occur.

Similarly, in an election, if I say Alan has a 95% chance to win but Beatrice wins, it looks like I was wrong "5% of the time", i.e. in 5% of possible outcomes. But one of those outcomes could happen and still have been unlikely.

Of course, the forecaster would also be mistaken if *they* took a 95% chance and called it a guarantee.

The Economist is defending their track record on political forecasts by explaining why they look wrong sometimes.

---

As a thematic tie-in, see this XKCD comic:

[image: XKCD comic]